# What does "-" symbol do in -$(VARIABLE) type of makefile commands?

Tags: linux, unix, makefile, build, gnu-make

In one of the makefiles that i came across, i found something like below in a recipe part of a rule.

```
-$(RM) $@
```

Here RM variable is equal to `rm` Unix command. (it is set in the top part of the code)

I know that here `$@` represent the target. And without the `-` symbol, above command removes that target file (maybe still with `-` symbol it still deletes it). But what is the use of `-` here?

Comment: See the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Errors) regarding error handling.

Comment: The presence of the variable is irrelevant.  The `-` here has the same meaning it does if the command was written `-rm /p/a/t/h`

Comment: But when i issue a command like `somelocation$ -rm dir/some-file` it give the error:

`Command '-rm' not found, did you mean:

  command 'srm' from deb secure-delete
...
`

Comment: The `-` is part of the _makefile_ syntax.  Make strips it from the recipe before invoking the shell; it has no meaning for the shell.  See the documentation link provided by G.M. in the first comment.